# dpkg can't find libicu even though it is installed

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm trying to install a package using dpkg like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i mypackage.deb
```

I get an error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mypackage:
 mypackage depends on libicu42 (>= 4.2-1); however:
  Package libicu42 is not installed.
```

I already have libicu52 installed on this machine, so I'm not sure why dpkg is giving me this trouble.

I tried to run `sudo apt-get install -f` to see if that would fix the missing libicu, but that just tried to remove `mypackage` instead. How can I get dpkg to acknowledge libicu52 as being OK for the dependency of libicu >= 4.2-1?

Comment: You have `libicu52` (fifty two), dpkg is asking for `libicu42` (fourty two)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: I had thought that it was asking for 42 *or better*. Isn't that what `>=4.2-1` means? If it can *only* work with `libicu42` then I'd need to force it into ubuntu 14, though I haven't been able to find an ubuntu package for `libicu42`. I know that the package *can* be installed into ubuntu 14 - I know it's been done, but I've never done it and I am having trouble figuring it out (the only documentation suggest running `sudo apt-get --fix-broken` which doesn't work since --fix-broken doesn't seem to be valid for this version of apt-get).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libicu52` and `libicu42` are two distinct packages, therefore no: `>=4.2-1` has no effect here.

You can grab the latest version of `libicu42` from [Lucid](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/libicu42) (Ubuntu 10.04), but use with care: that package is more than 4 years old, is unmaintained and may contain security bugs.

Comment: Adding the lucid repo to /etc/apt/sources.list and then installing libicu42 seems to have gotten around the problem. What I still find strange is that there are other workstations here that have libicu48 and libicu52 and they are able to install the package. But, at least I got it working on this machine!

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: adding the lucid repository was not a great idea... never mix two distribution repositories, you may encounter several compatibility problems. By the way, those other workstation were probably upgraded from lucid and that's why they have the package. Check with `apt-cache policy libicu42`